# race condition of OpenMP in nested loop

Tags: multithreading, openmp, race-condition

I am new to multithreading, I tried a few solutions, but I couldnt get it to work.

I am using nanoflann to do a knn search, and loop through the neighbours.
In order to remove repeated pairs, I had a check matrix. My code snippet looks like this:

```
    int count = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) 
    for (auto j = 0; j < mat.rows(); j++) {
        std::vector<double> query_pt = { mat(j,0), mat(j,1), mat(j,2) };
        resultSet.init(&ret_indexes[0], &out_dists_sqr[0]);
        mat_index.index_->findNeighbors(resultSet, &query_pt[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < resultSet.size(); i++)
        {
            if (checkmat(j, ret_indexes[i]) == 0) {

               checkmat(ret_indexes[i], j) += 1;
               checkmat(j, ret_indexes[i]) += 1;
               count += 1;
            }
            
        }
    }
    

    cout << "expected computation = 3741, actual computation = " << count << endl;
```

the checkmate is created as:

```
Eigen::MatrixXi checkmat;
checkmat.resize(mat.rows(), mat.rows());
checkmat.setIdentity();
```

My problem is that the actual computation is always less than expected. When I turn off the openmp, the actual computation is the same as expected. I am pretty sure the lookup in the checkmat causing the problem, because when I remove that I got the correct answer.

How should I define the checkmat to avoid the race condition?
The minimum running example is here:
[code example](https://github.com/BBBBBbruce/EigenFlann/blob/main/EigenFlann.cpp)

One of the solution I had, although I am not sure if this is the best choice:
I only parallel outer loop, and make the inner loop sequential:

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
    for (auto j = 0; j < mat.rows(); j++) {
#pragma omp critical
        {
            std::vector<double> query_pt = { mat(j,0), mat(j,1), mat(j,2) };
            resultSet.init(&ret_indexes[0], &out_dists_sqr[0]);
            mat_index.index_->findNeighbors(resultSet, &query_pt[0]);

            for (int i = 0; i < resultSet.size(); i++)
            {

                if (checkmat(j, ret_indexes[i]) == 0) {

                    checkmat(ret_indexes[i], j) += 1;
                    checkmat(j, ret_indexes[i]) += 1;
                    count += 1;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    

    std::cout << "expected computation = 3741, actual computation = " << count << std::endl;
```

Comment: If you put the whole code in a critical region it will work, but then you essentially get a serial execution.

Comment: I don't know if it's enough to get proper results, but at least `count`should have a reduction clause: `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:count)`

Comment: @PierU Thank you, I understand that. but in practice, if I don't put the whole block in critical, my count is always less than expected regardless of having a reduction or not.

Comment: Does `ret_indexes[]` change during the iterations?